# Javascript, dynamically change Video-Url - Video URL is set / Just Placeholder Poster Shown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, video

i want to dynamically change the Urls of two Videos. My Problem is that the first Video's URL is getting Changed and plays correctly and the second Video just changes the Videos-Url without Playing it. The Second Video still shows the Placeholder-Poster.

Without changing the Video.source.src my Page looks like This:
[image]

```html
<div class="container-fluid" id="container">
    <div class="cocoen">
        <video loop autoplay muted poster="img/placeholder_0.png">
            <source type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <video loop autoplay muted poster="img/placeholder_1.png">
            <source type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
```

When trying to set the Video-Sources (yes, i know that both video-urls are the same, its just for test purposes :p)

```js
var urls = ["img/small_1.mp4", "img/small_1.mp4"];
var sources = $("video > source").toArray();
sources[0].src = urls[0];
sources[1].src = urls[1];

startVideos();
```

Only the first (left) one is working:
[image]
But the Sources are correctly set on both videos.
[image]

I want to change the URLS more then Once, so just setting the URLS in the HTML isnt an Option.
If i set the src of video#1 to movie1 in html and video#2.src to movie2
and use JS to set video#1.src = movie2 and video#2.src=movie1
only the left video changes in display even tho the html has the correct src's.

[image]

I dont know if this Information is important, but this is how i start the Videos, after i set the URLS:

```js
function reduceRetryOnError(array, callbackFunction, functionToRetry) {
    success = array.reduce((acc, value) => acc && callbackFunction(value));
    if (!success) {
        console.log("Reduce failed: Retry in 300 ms");
        setTimeout(functionToRetry(), 300);
    }
}

function startVideos() {
    function startVideo(video) {
        if (!video) {
            return false;
        }

        if (video.paused) {
            video.play();
        }

        return true;
    }
    reduceRetryOnError($("video").toArray(), startVideo, startVideos);
}
```

I also tried to Pause and the start the Video again within the Starting Function.

Ty in advanced.

Comment: you should play each video when its event arrives, not both at the same time.

Comment: @rupps i want to compare video qualitys and therefore both should be playing at the same time

Comment: then you should  pause each one initially as they become ready, then play them all when all are ready n paused, bcs the time when videos are ready to play differ

Comment: @rupps how would i achieve something like that?